# List<T>.Find (Predicates / Lambda)

Tags: c#, lambda, predicate

Could someone tell me what the difference / advantage is between the following 3 Find options:

```
        List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();

        Employee tmp = new Employee();

        tmp.FirstName = "Randy";
        tmp.LastName = "Jones";
        Employees.Add(tmp);

        tmp.FirstName = "David";
        tmp.LastName = "Smith";
        Employees.Add(tmp);

        tmp.FirstName = "Michele";
        tmp.LastName = "Morris";
        Employees.Add(tmp);


        // Find option 1
        Employee eFound1= Employees.Find((Employee emp1) => {return emp1.LastName == "Jones";});

        // Find option 2
        Employee eFound2 = Employees.Find(emp2 => emp2.LastName == "Smith");

        // Find option 3
        Employee eFound3 = Employees.Find(
        delegate(Employee emp3)
        {
                return emp3.LastName == "Morris";
        }
        );
```

I have been reading about lambdas and predicates (which I suspect is somehow tied to the answer) but I can't put it all together.  Any enlightenment would be appreciated!

Thanks
David

Comment: What is the most readable approach for you?

Comment: they are the same, option 2 is shortest way, so possibly the best

Comment: I'd go with option 2, they are all functionally equivalent. The shortest syntax only works when there is one argument. You need the brackets for 0 arguments or more than 1.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but when build I think they will en up having the same CIL code.

Comment: Actually there is no absolute answer. All depends on scenario. Option 1 and 3 are used when you need couples of lines of code and option 2 is a shout hand for small snippet of code and very much readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is a [statement lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the second one is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the third is an [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

They are all functionally equivalent.

Comment: +1, now I know what to call these things!

Answer (score 1):

A predicate is a delegate to a method. In our next case, one that takes an int, and return a bool.
this is what a predicate look like:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
var predicate = new Predicate<int>(pairNumber);
var pair_numbers = list.FindAll(predicate);
```

then you'll have somewhere this method that will be called:

```
bool pairNumber(int arg)
{
    return (arg % 2 == 0);
}
```

Achieving the same with lambdas, would be shorter, and will look like this:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
var pair_values = list.FindAll(val => val % 2 == 0);
```

Saving you the need to create the predicate with a method.

If it's a complex operation, I would prefer a method, so I can see what happens and work with it.
If it's simple, lambda's all the way :)